# Samsung galaxy mini? pls help...about kies?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-kies, samsung-galaxy-mini

i installed kies software.But when i try to sync my photos and music into samsung galaxy mini,there is no option called multimedia under sync.what should i do?